# Keeping database history for update

Tags: c#, sql

If I have table consisting of 2 columns (id, name, userinsertedrow)

User A inserted 1 row (1, John, A)

User B updated row to (1, Michelle, B)

User B said "I did not updated anything"

What I can do ?

I can keep old record (1, John, A) and add new record (1, Michelle, B)

But this increases database size fast

Is there any way in SQL or using C# and SQL ??

Comment: You could record the time the row was last updated and who updated it, as extra columns in the table. You could get your app to write the fact than an update event occurred into a separate log file somewhere else. In the latest SQL server there's a built in history function you can switch on. Quite a few options if you use your imagination and/or do a bit of research

Comment: Can you mention what is the key of search for this function, But adding new column cannot be useful because update can occur more than 1 time

Comment: The feature in SQL server is called History Tables, if that's what you're asking

Comment: but History Tables is table. there are data repeated in each row increasing size of database

Comment: Is this a concurrency issue? Or is it just a matter of audit?

Comment: this is matter of audit to preserve users rights

Comment: Well if you want to record what has happened in the past then it's going to use up space. There's no magic solution to that. Using data uses space. But storage is pretty cheap these days, is it really such a big problem for you if the size increases?

Comment: Thank you for your time